# Can't send a post request to my Node-js RESTFUL API on postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have created my Nodejs restful api but yet i can't send a post request from postman. When i write directly to my database, the GET works correctly by displaying all the items.
below is my model file

**product.js**

```
// transform the models to rest, crud

var restful = require('node-restful');

module.exports = function (app, route) {

    // setup the controller for REST

    var rest = restful.model('product',
        app.models.product).methods([
            'get',
            'put',
            'post',
            'delete'
        ]);

    //Register the endpoint

    rest.register(app, route);

    // return middleware

    return function (req, res, next) {
        next();
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you get an error when trying to send a post request?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Postman? How you're making the request